# Moving an Image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to centre an image on a web page using HTML and CSS.

```css
.header {clear:both; position: relative; display: block; padding: 70px 20px 20px 20px; font-size: 40px; background-color: grey;} 
    #webpic1 {text-align: center !important;} 
    .Title {margin: 5px; padding: 10px; height: 90px; font-family: 'Comfortaa', arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 900; text-align: center;}
```

```html
 <div class="header"> 
    <div class="webpic"> 
    <img src="images/weblogo.png" alt="RRR" id="webpic1" height="230px" width="270px"> 
    </div> 
    <h3 class="title">RRR</h3>
```

Many Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your HTML is malformed (missing closing `div` tag) and it looks like your class name for the `h3` header is not lined up with what is in your CSS.

Comment: Here's the complete guide https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.webpic {
  text-align: center
}
```

or

```
#webpic1 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the target for your second style block to `.webpic` and enclose the `img` element in the same `div`, then your image should be centered.

```css
.webpic {text-align: center !important;}
```

```html
<div class="webpic"> 
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="RRR" id="webpic1" height="230px" width="270px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in css file and your image is in center.

```css
.webpic{text-align: center;}
```

If you want to center the image then you should text-align: center the above class or tag. thanks.